# How can I delete a paid Google Apps Business account without stopping my Postini service if I use Postini for the same domain?

Tags: google, google-workspace, google-apps-email, postini

I use Postini spam protection for my example.com domain. My example.com production email is *not* hosted by Google.  I also have a paid Google Apps for Business account for the *same* example.com domain.

I want to delete the example.com Google Apps account *without* deleting my Postini account.

Is this possible or by definition does a Postini setup require a Google Apps account with the same domain name to exist?

Comment: This isn't a definitive answer because it may not be 100% accurate... but, no. It looks like Google has married the two services so it isn't possible to use one without the other.

Comment: @EvanPlaice - If you put this as an answer rather than a comment then I'll mark it as the accepted answer.  Thx!

Answer (score 1):

If you are a paying customer, you can call them and ask them directly.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a definitive answer because it may not be 100% accurate... but, no. It looks like Google has married the two services so it isn't possible to use one without the other

Comment: Nowadays the Postini service is called Google Vault.